# Escaping git bash after reflog, or commit, etc

Tags: git, bash

When I'm using something like git reflog, I lose my ability to type in commands. I don't know what you look up, because I'm relatively new to bash.

So, what's the terminology I can use to go back to running git commands after running a reflog?

Comment: Oh. nice question :D I met this problem,too and maybe outside of stackoverflow, rarely questions like this :D

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Press `q` for quit and you will be back to the normal shell. CTRL + C would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply; I'll be choosing your answer in a few minutes here. What is switching the input method's purpose? Is there something I can look up besides just q?

Comment: @MorganDelaney - Have you used `less`? It is just piping the contents through less when the log, reflog etc. is beyond the screen size...See here for the options http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29 . Or press `h`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm sorry I wasn't more clear, but big thanks for the direction!

Comment: If the output from git is longer than a screen it will use `less`. `less` gives you functionality such as scrolling, searching, goto line numer etc...

Comment: @Eloff see that makes sense, I knew it wasn't just trying to block me out for no good reason! :) thx

Comment: For some perspective, try running log, reflog, diff, or whatever without piping it through `less`: `git --no-pager log` and you'll probably see why they thought piping through less was a good idea. You can turn it off for individual commands using aliases.

Comment: +1 for less. I've been using it from bash when viewing large files, if you learn the basic keyboard shortcuts its very useful.  Such as:  > to go to the end of the file, < to go to the top. Another interesting one is F I think, which makes it act like "tail -f", basically you can watch the end of a file in real time, like a log, and new lines come in. Another useful thing with less is that if you're viewing a color coded file like a log, try "less -R log/development.rb" - it will display the colors correctly.

Comment: Press ? to get the help - another useful command is "/" (find forward) and "?" (find backwards) - which lets you search with a regex. No GUI text editor can get close to less's speed when you're viewing large files.

Comment: CTL + C is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Type `q` for git bash and `:wq` then pressing enter for GitHub